# Excel Data storage

Tags: excel

I have a VBA code that will pop a inputbox for user to enter information then saved in a cell (I have this part working), than everytime when user click on the inputbox and enter new information, it should save the information on the next row instead of erasing the the same cell. (I need help on this part please )

```
Private Sub NewTraining_Click()

UserValue = InputBox("What Did You Trained?")

Range("J18").Value = UserValue    

UserValue = InputBox("Date?")

Range("K18").Value = UserValue    

UserValue = InputBox("Location?")

Range("L18").Value = UserValue    

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Don't you just need to change the `Range()`?  Can you please clarify what you're attempting to do, what's going wrong, etc?

Comment: so for now, there is an inputbox on my spreadsheet and it contain the code. When user click it, a small window pop up and ask user to input information ("What Did You Trained?", "Date?", "Location?") then the information will be saved on cell J18, K18, L18. AFTER it, when user click the inputbox and enter new information again, the code will rewrite the new information into same cell J18, K18, L18. BUT I do not want to rewrite the old data, I want the code to save the new data on J19, K19, L19. Everytime when user click on the inputbox, it should always save the new data to a previous cell +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `Offset`:

```
Sub t()
Dim trained As String, iDate As String, location As String
trained = InputBox("What Did You Trained?")
iDate = InputBox("Date?")
location = InputBox("Location?")

' What if they don't enter any value? You can exit sub at that point.
If trained = "" or iDate = "" or location = "" Then Exit Sub

Dim startCel As Range
Set startCel = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
startCel.Value = trained
startCel.Offset(0, 1).Value = iDate
startCel.Offset(0, 2).Value = location

End Sub
```

Comment: (@LitDuck - If it works, you can flag as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post; this removes your question from the Unanswered queue.)